# JavaScript Novice - using MathRandom () to display random image

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to display a random image on my html page I'm working on i have images all saved in the same folder as my webpage named 1-6 but it doesn't seem to work

here's the code I'm using:

```
    script type ="text/javascript">
    <!--
    document.write("<img src =\"" + Math.foor( 1 + Math.random() * 6 ) + ".jpg\" />");

    // -->
```

Comment: Change `foor` to `floor`. A quick glance at the error console would have told you that as well…

Comment: What "does not work"? Be a little more specific, please.

Comment: One of the first things you should learn as a javascript novice is how to open the developer console in your browser so that you can read the error messages caused by your JS code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Math has a function foor. I guess you mean floor ;)

```
document.write("<img src =\"" + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * 6 ) + ".jpg\" />");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.foor => Math.floor
```

Try using the javascript console in your browser to see what the errors are.